# handle OPTIONS request with django's built in server

Tags: django, http-status-code-405, http-options-method

I am trying to make OPTIONS requests work with django but I am currently only getting 405.
An answer I got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144224/django-breaks-cors-put-options-request) was that the server does not handle the OPTIONS request.

This is the View that handles the request:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from piston.utils import coerce_put_post

class TheView(View):

    @staticmethod
    def find_stuff(params):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def do_stuff(params):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def do_other_stuff(params):
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def delete_some_stuff(params):
        ...

    @method_decorator(staff_member_required)
    def get(self, request, id):
        result = self.find_stuff(id)
        return JsonResponse(result)

    @method_decorator(staff_member_required)
    def post(self, request):
        result = self.do_stuff(request.POST)
        return JsonResponse(result)

    @method_decorator(staff_member_required)
    def put(self, request, id):
        coerce_put_post(request)
        result = self.do_other_stuff(id,request.PUT)
        return JsonResponse(result)

    @method_decorator(staff_member_required)
    def delete(self, request,id):
        result = self.delete_some_stuff(id)
        return JsonResponse(result)
```

I am sending the request with jQuery's $.ajax(). This is the network log captured by chrome's dev tool:

- **Request URL** : `http://localhost`
- **Request Method** : OPTIONS
- **Status Code** : 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED

**Request Headers**

- **Accept** : */*
- **Accept-Encoding** : gzip,deflate,sdch
- **Accept-Language** : de,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
- **Access-Control-Request-Headers** : accept, origin, content-type
- **Access-Control-Request-Method** : PUT
- **Cache-Control** : no-cache
- **Connection** : keep-alive
- **Host** : foo
- **Origin** : `http://localhost`
- **Pragma** : no-cache
- **Referer** : `http://localhost/bar`
- **User-Agent** : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36

**Response Headers**

- **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials** : true
- **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** : Content-Type, Pragma, Cache-Control
- **Access-Control-Allow-Methods** : POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
- **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** : `http://localhost`
- **Allow** : post,get,options,put,delete
- **Content-Type** : text/html; charset=utf-8
- **Date** : Fri, 09 Aug 2013 09:39:41 GMT
- **Server** : WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.4

So how can I get the django server to handle it?

Comment: Can you post your Django view code? and the code that's making the OPTIONS request?

Comment: I've added the code to the opening post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suspect that `OPTIONS` request is returning a 405 error because an `options` handler hasn't been defined in your view class. Note that Django does not provide a default `options` handler.

Here is the code (django source code) that is responsible for calling the appropriate methods on your class:

```
# snippet from  django.views.generic.base.View

http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete', 'head', 'options', 'trace']

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
        handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
    else:
        handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

`options` is one of the default http method that can be handled in Django view. If the `options` handler hasn't been defined, the `dispatch` method returns a 405 error.

---

Here is an example of `options` method

```
class TheView(View):
    
    self.allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'options']
    def options(self, request, id):
        response = HttpResponse()
        response['allow'] = ','.join([self.allowed_methods])
        return response
```

Comment: I've added an options method liek you described but it still does return the 405

Comment: Nevermind. It was just some argument error. It works now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To create a valid preflight check you can set up your own [CORS Anywhere](http://corsanywhere.herokuapp.com) server or use a managed server like [Just CORS](https://justcors.com) as a reverse prop with added CORS headers.

Comment: This doesn't match with the OP question.